# Avoid using Transaction in splunk queries

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I am looking for alternate way to write splunk query without using transaction
Example
assuming r is a unique field in both the  searches
(sourcetype=* "search log 1") OR (sourcetype=* "search log 2") | transaction r startswith="X" endsWith="y" maxspan=4s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Typically*, [`stats`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/stats) will be found to be your friend here

However, without seeing sample data or what *actual* SPL you have tried so far, any answer is mostly going to be speculation :)

I'll happily update this answer if/when you provide such, but here's a possible start:

```
(index=ndxA sourcetype=srctpA "search log 1" r=*) OR (index=ndxB sourcetype=srctpB "search log 2" r=*)
| stats min(_time) as begintime max(_time) as endtime values(index) as rindex values(sourcetype) a rsourcetype by r
| eval begintime=strftime(begintime,"%c"), endtime=strftime(endtime,"%c")
```

Comment: Thank you Warren, let me try replacing that with the actual data i will get back to you

Comment: @maheshnair - did you ever get around to finding actual data to improve this answer?